# plotting timeseries of different years in a single plot for comparison and limiting sticks using Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have data that stretches 4 years in 5 minute resolution. I need to compare data in a single plot. I am using Seaborn package for plotting. I cannot plot with the data as-is because it will make the plot a four year time series plot. I converted the "Time Stamp" data to contain only day month and time using :

```
df_2018['no_year_dt'] = df_2018['Time Stamp'].dt.strftime('%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but the resulting column datatype is 'object' and not a 'datetime' format. Plotting using 'no_year_dt' column will result in all datapoints in x-axis ticks. (not readable)

I want the resulting plot to have limited x-ticks, say only the date like '1-1' '1-2' if I am plotting one months worth data.